# How to configure the SonarQube SCM integration sensor for Git

Tags: git, sonarqube

In our SonarQube 9.7.1 community instance, my team and I have started seeing a "noreply at github.com" email address as the author of lines of code on certain files. Here is an example:

[image: SonarQube interface]

Running `git blame` on the same file, I get this:

[image]

To see what was happening, I used Show Revision Information on the very same file in Eclipse. I got this:

[image]

Therefore, I think that when SonarQube writes "Author", it actually refers to the e-mail address of the "Committer" entry in the Eclipse popover, and that `git blame` refers to the user name of the "Author" entry in the Eclipse popover. My hypothesis is that the authoring information on each line contains both the user name and user email address of both the original commit author and the merge author.

We realized that this change was due to using the Squash Merge feature of GitHub. With Squash Merge, all commits on a branch are collapsed into a single commit on the destination branch of a merge request. This creates two authoring entries instead of only one in the case of a "standard" commit.

My question is this: is it possible to configure the SCM integration sensor in SonarQube to always use the "Author" information?

Answer (score 0):

On the [following link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scm-integration/) you can found next:

> **Known Issues**
>
> - Git doesn't consider old "Mac" line ends (CR) as new lines. As a result the blame operation will contain fewer lines than expected by
>   SonarQube and analysis will fail. The solution is to fix line ends to
>   use either Windows (CR/LF) or Unix (LF) line ends.
> - JGit doesn't support .mailmap file to "clean" email adress during the blame
> - **"Missing blame information..." and "Could not find ref..." can be caused by checking out with a partial/shallow clone, or using Git
>   submodules.**

My best guess is that your problem is part of known issues.

Comment: I came across this documentation page while researching the issue. The issue we are experiencing in my team seems different as the analyses succeed and blame information is present, just that code that comes from squash and merge is wrongly attributed.